# How to select alphabets only from string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to get alphabets only from string using sql server 2012 query.my data and desired result and code mentioned below.

```
select ',1,,3,,Mango,.,.,Apple,Orange' InputString,'MangoAppleOrange' ExecptedString
union all
select ',,,99,,,Apple,.,.,,Mango,,,Grape,,','AppleMangoGrape'
union all
select ',,,99,,-,Banana,/....*,.,,Mango,,,Grape,,','BananaMangoGrape'
```

Expected Result
[image]

I shared my attempts

```
declare @inputstr varchar(50)='12.Apple,98,Banana'
select SUBSTRING(@inputstr,1,ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z.''0-9]%',LTRIM(RTRIM(@inputstr))),0)-1,LEN(@inputstr)))
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please do show us your attempts.

Comment: Please don't include irrelevant tags

Comment: @Larnu i shared my attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using an rCTE (which could get very slow), I'm going to use Alan Burstein's [`NGrams8K`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams), which uses a tally and thus be faster, to deconstruct the string and then use `FOR XML PATH` to reconstruct it:

```
WITH YourTable AS
    (SELECT ',1,,3,,Mango,.,.,Apple,Orange' AS InputString,
            'MangoAppleOrange' AS ExecptedString
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ',,,99,,,Apple,.,.,,Mango,,,Grape,,',
            'AppleMangoGrape'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ',,,99,,-,Banana,/....*,.,,Mango,,,Grape,,',
            'BananaMangoGrape')
SELECT YT.InputString,
       (SELECT '' + NG.token
        FROM dbo.NGrams8k(YT.InputString,1) NG
        WHERE NG.token LIKE '[A-z]'
        ORDER BY NG.position ASC
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(MAX)') AS NewString
FROM YourTable YT;
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is definitely a user-defined function.  However, you can also do this with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select inputstring, inputstring as str, convert(varchar(max), '') as expected
      from t
      union all
      select inputstring, stuff(str, 1, 1, ''),
             (case when str like '[a-zA-Z]%' then expected + left(str, 1) else expected end)
      from cte
      where str <> ''
     )
select inputstring, max(expected)
from cte
group by inputstring;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=1cebeeff98e61f47007cf3934c970579) is a db<>fiddle.

If your strings can exceed 99 characters, then add `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Although I admit that an rCTE would be much slower on a large dataset or value, if that is the reason, you should advise so, so that both the OP and answer can learn from it. even if it is Gordon, we all still have a wealth of knowledge to learn. :)

Comment: @Larnu it isn't downvoted anymore. It wasn't me who downvoted his answer,but I just checked after seeing your comment. I agree that if someone downvotes, he should always post a comment as to what is the reason of the downvote, so we can all benefit. I have answers of my own that were mostly upvoted and got a few downvotes without comments, and I really wish I got them.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu no, but it was when i made the comment, I wasn't, however, going to keep track of the votes on this answer; my point was more to try and have the downvoter engage to express their reasoning. Downvotes without reasons can be frustrating when the person who answered doesn't have a reason as to why; we can't learn if we don't know what we did "wrong".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that returns only characters:

```
create function dbo.GetAlphanumeric 
(
    @inputString nvarchar(max)
)
returns table as return
(
    with t1(number) as (select 1 union all select 1),
    t2(number)  as (select 1 from t1 as a cross join t1 as b),
    t3(number)  as (select 1 from t2 as a cross join t2 as b),
    t4(number)  as (select 1 from t3 as a cross join t3 as b),
    nums(number) as (select row_number() over(order by (select null)) 
    from t4)

    select stuff( 
    (select   '' + substring(@inputString,nums.number,1)
    from nums
    where  patindex('%[^0-9a-za-z]%', substring(@inputString,nums.number,1)) =0
    for xml path('')),1,0,'') as execptedstring
)
```

And then call it in the select statement when you query the tabel that contain the information using:

```
select InputString, ans.ExecptedString
from YourTable 
cross apply dbo.GetAlphanumeric(InputString) ans
```

Comment: A `WHILE` would be a quite a slow way to do this. If a set based method is available (and they are) then they should be used. Plus the fact that you have a multi-line Scalar Function; which are slow unto themselves too. (Down vote is not mine, however, hopefully that person upvotes this comment if my reasoning is why, or adds their own reasoning).

Answer (score 0):

> go 
>   with temp1 as 
>   ( select ',1,,3,,Mango,.,.,Apple,Orange'
>   InputString,'MangoAppleOrange' ExpectedString union all select
>   ',,,99,,,Apple,.,.,,Mango,,,Grape,,','AppleMangoGrape' union all
>   select ',,,99,,-,Banana,/....*,.,,Mango,,,Grape,,','BananaMangoGrape'
>   ) select replace(replace(replace(
>   replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(InputString,',',''),1,''),'.',''),'/',''),'*',''),9,''),3,''),'-','')
>   as ExpectedString1 from temp1